# Auto generate full text search query like Google?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm new at FTS with SQL 2008 and I'm searching for a lib that convert Google-like keyword to FTS query for using with `CONTAINS()`.

I want the result to be:

```
a keyword => "a" OR "keyword"
another keyword -"long" => "another" OR "keyword" AND NOT "long"
```

Is there any lib for that kind of thing?

Any helps would be appreciated!

P/S: I'm using SQL 2008 with Entity Framework v4

Answer (score 1):

Try Lucene Full Text Search [Using Lucene Search](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but I'm using EF and afraid of something really new to me.